# g++: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory with simple example

Tags: g++

I try to make this code working: https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/pymodule and https://learnopencv.com/how-to-convert-your-opencv-c-code-into-a-python-module/
But when I run

```
g++ -shared -rdynamic -g -O3 -Wall -fPIC \ bv.cpp src/bvmodule.cpp \ -DMODULE_STR=bv -DMODULE_PREFIX=pybv \ -DNDEBUG -DPY_MAJOR_VERSION=3 \ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`  \ `python3-config --includes --ldflags` \ -I . -I/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include \ -o build/bv.so
```

on my windows machine. I get the following error:

```
g++: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
g++: error: opencv`: No such file or directory
g++: error: `python3-config: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-rdynamic'
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--includes'
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--ldflags`'
```

I also tried $(pkg-config --cflags) as suggested in other sides.

The pkg-config --version is 0.26.
g++ --version is g++ (i686-posix-sjlj, built by strawberryperl.com project) 4.9.2.
How can make the command work?

Comment: `\`command\`` and `$(command)` work in Unix-y shells such as bash. They will not work in cmd.

Comment: Thank you. What can I use in cmd?

Comment: No idea, use bash, there are many ways to run it on Windows.